# java - find all combinations of given numbers in a given array size and store into matrix

Tags: java

I am looking a way to create a matrix[][] in public static void main (String[] args), the purpose of the matrix[][]
is store  data[] in static void combinationUtil(), the original class permutation is output like

1 2 3 4

1 2 3 5

1 2 4 5

1 3 4 5

2 3 4 5

what I need to to is create the matrix[][] output is the same like class permutation, it is just like

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    matrix[][]=data[] ;

    for(int i=0,i<5;i++){

        for(int j=0,j<5;j++){

            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

the original class:

```
class permutation {

    static void combinationUtil(int arr[], int data[], int start, int end,int index, int r)
    {
        if (index == r)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<r; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(data[j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            return;
        }

        for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++)
        {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int r = 4;
        int n = arr.length;
        int data[]=new int[r];
        int start=0,end=n-1,index=0;
        combinationUtil(arr, data, start, end, index, r);
    }
}
```

Comment: why two main methods ?and why all this code ?

Comment: it is just one main methods, the first method is just what I want to create, the second main methods is just the original code main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code you can find the possible combinations for any known input array and sequence length. Its not that basic to understand but it is the only real solution that is non-recursive as far as i know. Hope this helps. :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                                                              


     int[] input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};    // input array                                                 
     int k = 4;                             // sequence length                                        

     List<int[]> subsets = new ArrayList<>();                                                         

     int[] s = new int[k];                  // here we'll keep indices                                
                                            // pointing to elements in input array                    

     if (k <= input.length) {                                                                         
         // first index sequence: 0, 1, 2, ...                                                        
         for (int i = 0; (s[i] = i) < k - 1; i++);                                                    
         subsets.add(getSubset(input, s));                                                            
         for(;;) {                                                                                    
             int i;                                                                                   
             // find position of item that can be incremented                                         
             for (i = k - 1; i >= 0 && s[i] == input.length - k + i; i--);                            
             if (i < 0) {                                                                             
                 break;                                                                               
             }                                                                                        
             s[i]++;                    // increment this item                                        
             for (++i; i < k; i++) {    // fill up remaining items                                    
                 s[i] = s[i - 1] + 1;                                                                 
             }                                                                                        
             subsets.add(getSubset(input, s));                                                        
         }                                                                                            
     }                                                                                                
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(subsets.toArray()));                                   

}                                                                                                     

    // generate actual subset by index sequence                                                       
   static int[] getSubset(int[] input, int[] subset) {                                                
        int[] result = new int[subset.length];                                                        
        for (int i = 0; i < subset.length; i++)                                                       
            result[i] = input[subset[i]];                                                             
        return result;                                                                                
    }                                                                                                 


  } 

  Outputs:
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
  [1, 2, 3, 5]
  [1, 2, 4, 5]
  [1, 3, 4, 5]
  [2, 3, 4, 5]
```